# How to send file in chunks using Ajax post request to Java Eclipse rest service

Tags: java, ajax, eclipse, rest

I am implementing PDF file upload functionality in my web application where I am trying to read file in javascript and dividing it in chunks using file.slice(start, stop), after reading this I am trying to send it in Ajax post request using loop till all chunks are send to service and  like shown below

```
self.ajaxCallToUploadFile = function (docId, finalChunk, fileName, data) {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', data);

    var serviceUrl = "http://localhost:8080/JerseyDemos/rest/upload/pdf/docId/finalChunk/FileName";

    return $.ajax({
        url: serviceUrl,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (rdata) {
            alert(rdata.d);
        },
        error: function (errorData) {                    
            alert(errorData.responseText);
        },
        data: formData,
        cache: false,               
        contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
        //contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        async: false
    });
};
```

With file chunk as data I am sending other parameters in query string in service URL.
I am new to Java and Java services, I am using Eclipse to write services. I tried to read this file chunk as Inputstream but it fails. I tried to search for specific answer on this question but everywhere I am getting answer to how to send file from java code to java service. Here I am expecting answer on how to should send it from javascript to Java rest service and how to read it in Java rest service.

Please help me on this as i am struggling to implement this functionality 
below is the Java rest service method decoration I tried with.

```
 @Path("/upload")
public class JerseyService {
    @POST
    @Path("/pdf/{docId}/{chunkNumber}/{finalChunk}")
    @Consumes({ MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA})
    public Response uploadPdfFile(@PathParam("docSetId") final Integer docId,
            @PathParam("chunkNumber") final Integer chunkNumber, @PathParam("finalChunk") final Boolean finalChunk,
            @FormDataParam("file") FormDataBodyPart file)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some error in your javascript ajax url

looking at serviceUrl `http://localhost:8080/JerseyDemos/rest/upload/pdf/docId/finalChunk/FileName` there is a *mismatch* in the expected types of your java Rest Service (RS) parameters and your javascript url:

- `docId` is a String in your URL, yet in your Java RS, it is marked as `Integer` and its called `docSetId`.
- your java RS ist expecting some types: `docId -> Integer`, `chunkNumber-> Integer`, `finalChunk -> Boolean`. Yet you are sending only Strings as url (docId/finalChunk/FileName).

The java RS mapper can not locate your rest service method to order your request.
Just fix your URL. As Example try:

```
serviceUrl = "http://localhost:8080/JerseyDemos/rest/upload/pdf/203/4/myFileName"
```

**EDIT**:

if your parameters are ok, please check that your browser *really* sends your 
data chunks to the server. It can send your other (text) parameters (docId, chunkNumber,and finalchunk), but having trouble sending your *binary* data. You can check that by using firebug (if you are testing with mozilla) [see how to](https://www.sitepoint.com/http-request-net-panel-httpfox-fiddler2/). Monitor each upload you send to see if they actually *leave* your browser. Inspect your request to see if a data chunk also leaves, and which name it bears.

if it doesn't leave your browser, or leave but is not well formed, then the  problem is on the client side (your javascript slice and appending code is at fault here).

if however it leaves your browser, then try to process the chunk using `InputStream` like this:

```
@Path("/upload")
public class JerseyService {
       @POST
       @Path("/pdf/{docId}/{chunkNumber}/{finalChunk}")
       @Consumes({ MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA})
       public Response uploadPdfFile(@PathParam("docSetId") final Integer docId,
       @PathParam("chunkNumber") final Integer chunkNumber, 
       @PathParam("finalChunk") final Boolean finalChunk,
       @FormDataParam("file") InputStream  file){

             // do something with file like 
             int nextByte = -1;
             while((nextByte  = file.read()) != -1){
             // process your byte here
           }

       }

     }
```

Comment: Thank you @arthur for your reply. I am sending my docId as interger only from my URL. And JAVA RS code gets hit when I am sending request when removing file parameter(I modified docId to docSetId), My main problem is my service is not reading file as chunk, without file input parameter it is always working. How should i read those chunks in JAVA RS and how to send it in Ajax request

Comment: Hi @arthur, I tried above code in service to read file chink as InputStream but service fails to read that. I am using below function in javascript to read file   function readFileInChunk(file, offset, readCount, callback) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = function (evt) {
                if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) {
                    callback(evt.target.result);
                }
            };
            var blob = file.slice(offset, readCount);
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
        }

Comment: @umesh07 please what is callback supposed to as function ? can you please post the whole code e.g. your `html file ` where you take the file from, your `complete ajax and js` code that chunks and send the code as well as your Java RS file ? that would help please

Comment: Here Callback method sends what data is read by filereader and then I am using that data as chunk to send in Ajax call.I am calling it like     readFileInChunk(file, offset, offset + chunkSize, function (data) {
                    fileBuffer = data;     
                    self.ajaxCallToUploadFile(docId, isFinalChunk, fileBuffer, function (error) {
                        if (error.responseText !== "")
                            isError = true;
                        // Add retry login depending on return status code
});
offset = offset + chunkSize;                    
});